# What tag to use for questions about the Beowulf epic, or about the Kalevala?

Tags: discussion, tags

What tag should we use for questions about the Beowulf epic, or about the Kalevala?  There appear to be no such questions yet, but I hope somebody will try to ask good ones soon.

Suggestions from chat are: [anglo-saxon](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglo-saxon) or [beowulf](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beowulf); and [karelian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karelian) or [finnish](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finnish) respectively.

Update: should we tag Beowulf questions with [celtic](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celtic) as well?  That tag already exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we have tags for specific elements in a culture?](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/61/should-we-have-tags-for-specific-elements-in-a-culture)

Comment: And now we have our first such question: http://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1055/197 Do the seemingly random timespans in the Kalevala creation story have any significance?

Comment: And the first question about Beowulf too: http://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1120/197 Why did Beowulf's men carry weapons?

Answer (score 9):

Considering the precedents of [mabinogion](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mabinogion), [popol-vuh](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popol-vuh), and [arthurian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthurian), I see no reason why Beowulf shouldn't be given its own [beowulf](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beowulf) tag at this stage. Myth.SE may decide later to not use individual tags for each work, but for now at least there's no harm.

Additionally, questions on the topic can be tagged [english](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) or [anglo-saxon](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglo-saxon)[old-english](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-english), with the latter two being synonyms. Whichever direction we eventually go with should be consistent with a decision on the [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) vs [ancient-greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-greek) situation.

Basically, IMHO **we don't have to limit ourselves to *one* tag**. Someone browsing English mythology questions could very reasonably be also interested in Beowulf related questions.